# Can you create a coil gun with asymmetric forces?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

One of the problems in making a coil gun shoot high-velocity projectiles is that after the projectile passes the mid-point of the coil, it experiences suck-back: a force that slows the projectile and tries to bring it back to the center. You can get around this to some extent by shutting off the coil at the right time, but there are limits to how fast the magnetic field can vanish.

Is it possible to create an asymmetric set of forces so that even if you don't shut down the field quickly enough, the suck-back is a lot weaker? I was thinking of several possible ways to do this:

- Add an outside iron sheath to the first half of the coil and not the second half. Would this make the flux in the first half stronger than the flux in the second half?
- Add an inside iron cylinder in the second half of the coil that the projectile travels through. Would the flux going through this iron cylinder take away from the flux on the projectile?
- Wind the coil asymmetrically so that the loops at the firing end are much denser than the loops at the starting end. Would this create an asymmetric field that is shorter at the firing end so there would be less time for the force to act?
- Some combination of the above?
- Some other way to produce asymmetric forces?